# Node Reference in LinkedLists

Tags: java

After trying to figure out why this works and failing to do so, I wanted to ask you guys why this code works.

Head over to the second while loop. By this time we have a set that is filled with elements of ListA. When we run the .contains(b) I was confused about why this returns 8, and not 1 which comes before 8. I know it has something to do about references but I could not grasp that concept. If someone understands it better please let me know.

Look at this link for an example case.

https://assets.leetcode.com/uploads/2020/06/29/160_example_1_1.png

https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB){

        Set<ListNode> set = new HashSet<>();
        ListNode a = headA; ListNode b;
        
        while(a != null){
            set.add(a);
            a = a.next;
        }

        b = headB;
        while(b != null){
          if(set.contains(b)){
            return b;
          }
          b = b.next;
        }

        return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand is that in your entire method, you don't actually change any of the ListNodes or even create any new ones. Your memory (for the most part... but let's not dwell on that) stays the same. All you do is play around with references.

**Attention: I made a mistake and gave the final TreeNode the value 6 instead of 5. It's the one in the center on top (and the one the final arrow points to). Please pretend it's a 5.**

Let's say this is our memory:

[image]

At the beginning, it's empty. Now this is how it might look after we added all those nodes.

[image]

*Technically, that's of course not how it looks, but I'm just trying to illustrate a few things here and as far as understanding goes, you don't need to know the exact details of what is where in your memory.*

Just try to understand that each of these nodes is its own object and needs its own space in your memory.

Now those nodes are linked. What that means is that each one (except for the last one) has a reference to another node.
It means that the variable doesn't exactly hold a value but just points to a place in your memory where that node can be found.

To illustrate that, I drew some arrows here:

[image]

Now this already looks an aweful lot like your lists.

Okay. Next, you have two head elements. Those are variables as well, but again, they don't hold actual values but just point to something that's in your memory (which makes them references). Like this:

[image]

So let's take your first while. I will color the nodes in once they are part of the set, but only for readability. If I was being consistent, every single variable in that set would have an arrow pointing to the corresponding TreeNode in memory (i will show what it actually looks like in the end and you'll understand why I didn't want to draw it like that):

[image]

Now, we will start with your second while. This one is very important:

[image]

Okay, so if we return b at that point, it will once again just be a reference pointing to the TreeNode in our memory with the value 8.
And if you look at that TreeNode (which hasn't changed since the beginning), it still points to the next one so yeah... you still have everything that comes after it.

Comment: so what you guys mean is that the nodes with values one have different references, however, with the node with value 8 has a similar reference. I get it thanks. However, when we return b, how does it return the 8 > 4> 5 and not just node reference where we are at right now (which is 8).

Comment: I changed my answer completely, hope this helps answer that, although I just realized I put a 6 at the end which should be a 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are adding list nodes to the set, not the values of list node (i..e not a.val but a). So, when you check for nodes using second while loop, you see that the node with value '1' is not present in set. You will see your expected output when you push a.val instead of 'a' into set. But, I see from the links given that you are trying to find intersection point, for which this logic holds good.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather easy:

The set contains `ListNode` elements which are identified by their reference not by their value.

Basically, the contents of `A` and `B` have partly different references and the set contains the following:

```
Set: 4(A),1(A),8(A/B),4(A/B),5(A/B)
```

In the brackets, you find where this reference is contained.

So just write the second while down:

```
b = 5(B)

Second While:
false
b = 6(B)
false
b = 1(B)
false
b = 8(A/B)
true
```

It's returning true because the reference (pointer) to the `ListNode` with the value `8` is the same as in `A`. The third `ListNode` of `B` has the value `1`, but the second `ListNode` of `A` whose value is also `1` is a different instance of `ListNode`, thus returning false.

Comment: so what you guys mean is that the nodes with values one have different references, however, with the node with value 8 has a similar reference. I get it thanks. However, when we return b, how does it return the 8 > 4> 5 and not just node reference where we are at right now (which is 8).

Answer (score 0):

The reason in we check the node not the value which is inside that node e.i

```
if(set.contains(headB)){
   return headB;
}
```

**Consider the node as reference - if both pointed to the same reference then only that pointed(reference) node is considered as an intersection.**

**See this solution:**

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {
        HashSet<ListNode> set = new HashSet<ListNode>();
        
        if(headA==null ||headB==null)
            return null;
        
        while(headA!=null){
            set.add(headA);
            headA = headA.next;
        }
        
        while(headB!=null){
            if(set.contains(headB)){
                return headB;
            }else{
                headB = headB.next;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```